# Error while loading shared libraries: libyaml-0.so.2: file too short

Tags: command-line, arch-linux, shared-library, flatpak

I've installed flatpak on ARCH-LINUX and rebooted, the next thing to do was test it on terminal, then I typed: flatpak

And then:

```
flatpak: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/libyaml-0.so.2: file too short
```

Some programs that I've installed before this was Telegram, but it had the same error with the exception that instead of libyaml-0.so.2, it was:

```
telegram-desktop: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/libgiomm-2.4.so.1: file too short
```

What is that error and how to solve it?

Comment: The library has been damaged. You need to reinstall the package that provides it.

Comment: I've done this now with the two libraries, but the error is still there

Comment: On my system, libyaml-0.so.2 is a symlink: `/usr/lib/libyaml-0.so.2 -> libyaml-0.so.2.0.9`. What does `ls -l /usr/lib/libyaml-0.so.2.0.9` return?